# Running Laravel from a git repo

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

I can install Laravel and get it up and running just fine using the [installation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) process, but what I don't understand is how I'm suppose to be able to push that same source code and be able to run it from a repo, like [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git). When I do this, cloning it in doesn't allow me to be able to run `php artisan` anything.

Moreover, when I have a working directory, pushing that up to a repo, cloneing it back down, still doesn't work. I'm unable to run `artisan`. The only way I can do this is through composer from the install instructions, which would create a new project.

Please guide me; I'm at a loss here.

Comment: can you show what is message when you clone?

Answer (score 2):

Its because the vendor directory is not included when you clone.

To solve it run `composer install` where you cloned it, and then `artisan` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you had checked `.gitignore` file, you might have already got this.

Because we don't commit dependency into git repository. We have to manually install it via `composer install` for a fresh copy of a project in any machine. Once you have local copy, you only require to update it or install when any update into `composer.lock` file.