# Is there a place to get the laravel `vendor` folder in one spot?

Tags: php, git, laravel, vendors

I realize that this is what composer is used for, but I don't particularly like it. It makes sense, but it annoys me that laravel5's github doesn't work out of the box because it's `vendor` directory is somewhat large and isn't necessarily laravel5, although laravel does require it.

It also puzzles me why composer doesn't get it itself.

I would expect to be able to

`git clone the_laravel5_github_url`

`composer install`

and be able to run as it seemed like you were able to do [at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530224/running-laravel-from-a-git-repo), but for some reason now, the vendor directory isn't there. I feel like this makes laravel harder to set up as it isn't so obvious.

Is there a place where someone can get an recent version of this? I find it disappointing that there is no mention of it on their readme and that you were able to do it before and still can't despite using `composer install`.

Comment: Please let us know the exact problem that you are facing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install Composer on your OS using this command
   `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`.
2. Move the **composer.phar** file to  /usr/local/bin/ with this command
   `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`. This will enable you to access composer globally.
3. `git clone` your project.
4. Make a **vendors** folder in the root of your project.
5. cd to root of your project and run `composer update`. This command will look for **vendors** folder in the root and will install all the packages required by your project in it.

Happy Coding

Thank you :)

Comment: Will adding it root allow all projects refer it from that location? I mean how laravel would find the `autoload.php` file in the root dir instead of its home directory?

Comment: open `bootstrap/autoload.php`. There, you include the vendor's autoload.php  `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` . You just have to alter this path and then you will be able to to use laravel functionality according to your requiremente

Answer (score 0):

Use composer install in the same folder of your app. Try composer update. And install composer globally in your OS.