# unable to run Laravel project on live server

Tags: php, laravel

In my localhost I can run Laravel using composer without any problem. But I don't know how to move my Laravel project to live server.

I just copied all items which is in Public folder to Public_html.
Then other items are placed into Laravel folder. Put this folder into Public_html. I have changed the index.php coding like this.

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But still my site shows

> page isn’t working..is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500

Public_html folder like this [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server)

Comment: I have tried that way also many time. But same error occurs. That is why I have changed like above.

Comment: Not sure if it would make any difference but did you clear your config cache etc?

Comment: What I will do on config cache ? @Andy Holmes kindly explain

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` i don't think it'll alter your problem. Unfortunately I'm not sure on how to fix your issue, the linked question to me should fix your issues. Who are you hosting with?

Comment: Hosting with "direct admin". php artisan cache:clear .. how can I run this command on Live server ? I can done this in my localhost only.. I don't know how to do on live server

Comment: Then you need to speak to your host about accessing the command line

Comment: Have answered a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461322/upload-laravel-5-to-server-subfolder/35474800#35474800 have a look, might help you.

Answer (score 0):

**if you can not provide a link to the web root of the shared folder!**

1. All except the Public folder to move to a higher level, such as a folder laravel - http://prntscr.com/bryvu7
   (Maybe on hosting your folder - public. not a folder public_html)
2. Change file publi_html/index.php
   line

   `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And line

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

3. Change file laravel/server.php
   line

   `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`

to

```
require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

Comment: I have changed as like you told now. But still shows same "page isn’t working.. is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Answer (score 0):

This error you can get due to vendor folder missing in live server Please follow this is this answer. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31935081/7013481)